# How to properly fix the 'error in locking authority file' when I try to start my VNC session

Tags: vnc, quota, xauth

When I try to start my VNC using this command:

```
/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1900x1020
```

I get the following error:

```
xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/maindir/.Xauthority
sh: line 1: /home/maindir/.vnc/[*mymachine:port*].log: Disk quota exceeded
Unable to start Xvnc, exiting
```

The error says that I exceeded my disk quota but I still have 16GB free memory (I don't know if it is even related to this quota).
I read over other threads that deleting this Xauthority will solve the issue but I am not sure that it is the most proper way to solve my issue. If anyone can explain why I get this issue and how to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: Disk quota is about allowed (!) disk space, not RAM. Check 'quota -u yourusername'.

Comment: Ok I run that command and yes I have reached my quota. btw the 16GB is ROM not  RAM. I started deleting stuff and now I have access. Post your comment as an answer, it solved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk quota is about allowed (!) disk space, which can be checked using 'quota -u yourusername'.

In order to get along smoothly you might need to free up some more disk space.

Checking 'df -h' (or other means) might show available space though your quota is smaller, as configured by your local BOFH.